# Python String Manipulation - finding unique numbers in many strings

Tags: python, string, variables, unique

I am looping through variables of the form - V15_1_1. The middle and last number in this string changes for each variable. I want to create a string of all the unique middle numbers. 
For example, I may have V15_1_1, V15_2_3, V15_2_6, V15_12_17,V15_12_3 which would return a text string of '1,2,12'

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: so what have you tried to do to solve this yourself?

Comment: order does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
my_list = ['V15_1_1', 'V15_2_3', 'V15_2_6', 'V15_12_17','V15_12_3']

def unique_middle_values(input_list):
    return set([i.split('_')[1] for i in input_list])

unique_middle_values(my_list)
{'1', '12', '2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split each string into the numbers you want, for instance by splitting on the _ character and removing any non-numeric characters from each substring. Then you have them in order from left to right, and add each of them to one of three sets for the left, middle and right numbers. Sets can only have the same entry once. You can then print the contents of the sets to get what you want. If needed they can be sorted first. All of these things I've described can be individually googled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set()`.

```
first_set = set()
second_set = set()
for item in list:
    v, num1, num2 = item.split('_')
    first_set.add(num1)
    second_set.add(num2)
print ', '.join(s for e in first_set)
print ', '.join(s for e in second_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
>>> def fun(var):
    l = []
    for a in var:
        middle = a.split('_')[1]
        if middle not in l:
            l.append(middle)
    return ','.join(l)

>>> fun(['V15_1_1', 'V15_2_3', 'V15_2_6', 'V15_12_17', 'V15_12_3'])
'1,2,12'
```